# Search Results Web Part does not display correct thumbnail

Tags: sharepoint-online, publishing-page, modern-pages, thumbnail, search-results-webpart

I've got a search results web part on a page, targeting a document library with .gif and .png files, but getPreviewSrc returns a different value from getUrl (preview returns an image from outside of that library). Editing the  Card Info template and changing getPreviewSrc breaks the web part, showing nothing on it. Any workaround so that the correct image loads on the previewImg div?

```
<div class="ms-Grid-col ms-sm12 ms-md6 ms-lg4">
                        <div class="singleCard">
                            <a href="{{getUrl item}}">
                                <div class="previewImg lazy" data-bg="url('{{getPreviewSrc item}}')" style="background-position: 50% 50%; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <li class="ms-ListItem ms-ListItem--document" tabindex="0">
                                <div class="cardInfo">
                                    <span class="ms-ListItem-primaryText"><a href="{{getUrl item}}">{{Filename}}</a></span>
                                    <div class="ms-ListItem-selectionTarget"></div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible fix. Replace `{{getPreviewSrc item}}` with `{{PictureThumbnailURL}}`

Answer (score 0):

I use PictureURL in JavaScript apps and in Display Templates.  It would give you the full sized image instead of the thumbnail.